# File Copy using mmap

Tags: linux, unix, networking, memory-management, mmap

Problem - Transfer a file of size 350 MB from linux networking box 1 to another linux networking box 2 on the fly dynamically when the box 2 requests for it.

System has limited memory of 1 GB and the file which is of size 350 MB is stored on the disk. The system is actually busy doing a lot of other things.

What is the best approach to take to transfer the file on the fly on demand automatically? If I read the complete file from the disk and store it on RAM before transferring that would actually take up a lot of memory. If I want to avoid that, then whether using mmap to transfer the file would help? How would mmap fit in this scenario?

Comment: It's worth noting that, unless there is a really good reason to use a custom protocol, you should probably serve the file using an off-the-shelf package such as Apache or nginx or openssh (which includes sftp functionality) which has already been optimised, and don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you can (and should) use a buffered copy, along the lines of:

```
while (read some data from the input into a buffer) {
    write data from the buffer to the output
}
and you're done
```

The buffer does not need to be large. Something on the order of 64 KB should be sufficient for most situations.

**For the sending end only**, you may be able to use [the `sendfile()` system call](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile) as an optimization.